# How to connect MongoDB Compass using MLab connection string

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I have database hosted on MLab and I am trying to connect it with Compass. I am using host and port given in connection string but it is showing error, here is my screenshot:

[image: Compass]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 45):

Had same problem manage to solve it like this:

[image: mLab user tab]

A. Go to your db in mlab and in the tab choose "users"

B. Create a new user ex: username: `admin`  password: `123456`

C: Go to compass and fill it this way

#### Example of your connection path

> ds012345.mlab.com:56789/myDBname

*hostname*

> ds012345.mlab.com

*port*

> 56789

*authentication: username /password*

> admin // or the name of the user you created in step A 
>   123456 // or password for the user you created in step A

*authentication database*

> myDBname // the name of your database in mlab

Comment: For me, Authentication Database is the problem.

Comment: The main thing was **Authentication Database**, that was admin by default.

Comment: This should be set as correct answer! Solved my problem

Comment: Solved! Still I don't understand why we need to create another database user.

Answer (score 12):

I just had the same problem.

I fixed it by updating my version of MongoDB Compass. No problems encountered with version 1.15.4.

Also, Authentication Database should not have the value "admin" but the name of the DB to connect you.

To make your connection easier, don't hesitate to copy your entire connection string into the clipboard. Compass detects it and proposes to automatically fill in the connection form.

Comment: Yes,"Authentication Database" means "the database you want to connect to".

Answer (score 10):

The problem that I had was the `Authentication Database` Compass filled in automatically wasn't correct for my setup. By default, this was pointing to `admin` but it needs to point to the database that the user is associated with.

Summed up: The database of `admin` didn't exist.

Just to rule it out, double check what database you're pointing to. It should be in the name, like `ds739176/database_name` where `database_name` is, you guessed it, the name of your database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the case for me too!

Answer (score 4):

The required credentials are not your login credentials to MLab,
instead these are database user credentials.

### How to get them:

1. click on your DB on MLab.
2. go to users tab and create new user.
3. use the created users credentials to access db.
4. set authenticationdatabase to be your database.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. MongoDB url was working in code but `Authentication failed` was showing in MongoDB Compass.

When I checked, my mongodb password was `iam%40me1234`.

Here I'm using `%40` HTML hex code in the password for `@` character.

So, If we will use the original character in the password like `iam@me1234` in MongoDB Compass then it will work great.

Here is a full list of Hex [codes](http://lnnk.in/b6g)

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

1. Click on "Fill in connection fields individually" option in Compass.
2. Enter the hostname (Example ds051234.mlab.com)
3. Enter PORT (Example 12345)
4. Select Username/password in the Authentication option.
5. Enter username and password (Create a new user in mlab.com for your database)
6. Authentication Database (Just enter the "database name" in this field. Example: heroku_8967jgy5)

I hope this will help you.